# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm receiving an wrong number of arguments error when trying to send an activation email.

> Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace Application Trace | Framework Trace
>   | Full Trace
>
> app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:8:in `account_activation'
>   app/models/user.rb:66:in`send_activation_email'
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'

*user_mailer.rb:*

```
def account_activation
  @user = user
  mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
end
```

*users_controller.rb:*

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    @user.send_activation_email
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

*models/user.rb:*

```
# Sends activation email.
def send_activation_email
  UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
end
```

According to my understanding I do not pass a wrong number of arguments to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `self` as an argument

```
UserMailer.account_activation(self)
```

where as method `account_activation` don't accept any argument

Change your method to `account_activation(user)` as you are using `user.email` in it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing:

```
def account_activation(user)
```

You are passing `self` on calling, so the method needs a parameter.